# c# Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric

Tags: c#, asp.net

I writing a Asp.net website.I want to insert a value my mssql database.But I am getting such an error :

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Error converting data type nvarchar to
>   numeric.

My code:

```
SqlCommand cmdKaydet = new SqlCommand(commandText, con);
cmdKaydet.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dovizkur", txt_DovizKuru.Text);
cmdKaydet.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: How does your `commandText` look? It looks like you're trying to add text as a parameter when it's a number in your table.

Comment: string commandText= "INSERT INTO EVRBAS(DOVIZKUR) VALUES(@dovizkur)";

Comment: Is `DOVIZKUR` a number or text?

Comment: Check if value `txt_DovizKuru.Text` is valid numeric value

Comment: txt_DovizKuru.Text is 100% not numberic value if it is a control. simply parse it to int

Comment: But DOVIZKURU is numeric in mssql database

Comment: I converting integer but this time I getting  a format error.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @SKLTFZ it is numeric

Comment: please check that, if it is numeric in mssql, then you need to convert it to decimal in .NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Sorry to low reputaion to comment so)
Try the below options.

```
Convert.ToDouble(txt_DovizKuru.Text);
//or
Convert.ToDecimal(txt_DovizKuru.Text);
```

Normally the error will trigger here already if the text is not any numeric value. 
Please post your input exactly and the error.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
cmdKaydet.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dovizkur", Convert.ToInt32(txt_DovizKuru.Text));
```

Comment: I tried but unfortunately it doesn't working.Format exception error

Comment: My value is numeric in sql . I am converting Decimal but it doesn't working.

Comment: @Emre Aslan what is the error when you converting txt_DovizKuru.Text to decimal? have you checked that txt_DovizKuru.Text is valid to be converted to decimal? simply you can pass a 0 to your query and see if it is ok. if yes then i think it is because txt_DovizKuru.Text is not valid to be Convert.ToDecimal directly, try to use TryParse instead and give it a default value. or you can set your SQL field to nullable.

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, one should always add an explanation to it.